# Java executable converts / to a period

Tags: java, shell

I am trying to create a java program to find the users ip address. The prgram compiled fine, and my problem is that when i try to run it using the `java` command, i get an error saying it could not find or load the class file. i found that it was changing any '/' to a '.'. I have tried:

```
java /home/pi/Desktop/ip.class
```

and it returns:

Error: Could not find or load main class .home.pi.Desktop.ip.class

prefixing the escape character `\` to all of the `/` had no effect.

the same thing occured to any path i tried, how can i get the `java` program to recieve / instead of . ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you want `java` to run a specific class, you pass the *class name*, not the location of the file containing that class.

If the `.class` file is in not in the current working directory, you need to specify the classpath argument (`-cp`). Something like:

```
java -cp <location of the class> <fully-qualified name of the class>
```

In your case, it might be:

```
java -cp /home/pi/Desktop ip
```

but you might need to qualify the `ip` class name with the package it is declared to be in, e.g.

```
package my.package;
class ip {}
```

would need to be

```
java -cp /home/pi/Desktop my.package.ip
```